# Cache issue in Sitefinity/IIS, what can i do?

Tags: iis, sitefinity

I have a problem which I am struggling to identify. It may be a Sitefinity(CMS)-problem or it may be a IIS-problem.

Explanation:
I have a external database, where the user login-information is stored. When I change my information in the external database the changes does not affect the Sitefinity-page.  But if I wait for many hours OR restart the website in IIS, the changes are made and affect the sitefinitypage.

So, as far as  I can see this could be either Sitefinity or IIS.
I tried to disable the Sitefinity OutPut Cache, but it did not help.
Now I want to try to do something in IIS, but I am not very familiar with IIS. Do you hae any idea of what should I do/try?

Comment: Looks like a cache issue, but even if you disabled the Output cache - some of the sitefinity controls, e.g. UserProfiles are using their internal cache too. Maybe you can try creating a simple custom widget that displays the User profile info using the Sitefinity API and see if that resolves it

Comment: What Veselin said... there's even a webservice route you can use to get login info, it's used by the loginstatus widget.  I THINK /RestApi/loginstatus or something

Answer (score 0):

Sitefinit has caching profiles. The standard (default) one should be 20 minutes, sliding expiration if I remember correctly. Go to the page, click Title & Properties. In the dialog scroll down until you see "Advanced" seection. It's probably collapsed by default.
Expand it and see if Caching profile is anything different than "No caching". If so - make it "No caching" and save. Re-test.

This is output cache. You can think of it as saving the html page on the first request and then serving this saved copy. The cache invalidates on multiple events. For example if you publish the page - it will invalidate the cache.